# Default button color

Tags: javascript, html

Found out that the default button for enter on a form is the first `submit` type.  This works but what do I specify for the button to look like the default button, i.e. the one that is highlighted.  If I set the background color this changes the button appearance from the standard button look.

Here is the form HTML.

```
<form id="login_user_id" name="login_user_form"> 

<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="add" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="edit_user" id="edit_user" value="y" />
<table cellspacing="0px"> <tr><td>Username or email:</td></tr><tr><td>
<input type="text" name="username_email" id="username_email" size="30" value="" class="inline_input"/></td> </tr> <tr><td>Password:</td></tr><tr><td>
<input type="password" name="user_passwd" id="user_passwd" size="30" class="inline_input"/></td> </tr> </table></td></tr> </table> 
<button id="login" type="submit" onclick="login_user(); return false;" style="width: 63px;">Login</button> 
<button id="cancel" onclick="cancel_login(); return false;" style="width: 63px; float: right; margin-right:8px; position: relative; top: -22px;">Cancel</button> 

</form>
```

Comment: I clearly didn't understand what you meant by: `for the button to look like the default button, i.e. the one that is highlighted`

Answer (score 0):

The statement “If I set the background color this changes the button appearance from the standard button look” pretty much summarizes the limitations. You can style buttons, but many types of styling deprive buttons of the features they have as per system defaults. Browsers use some built-in routines for rendering buttons, but many CSS settings make them deviate from this. It is generally not possible to imitate the common button style, partly because it varies by system, partly because it has rendering features that cannot be described in CSS as currently defined and implemented.

So just let buttons look like buttons. If you cannot do that, style *all* of your buttons in some uniform way; it would be misleading to make the non-default button look like a common button and the default button look like something else.

There is really no need to indicate one of the buttons as the default button if you just remove the other button. (See [Reset / Cancel Button Considered Harmful](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20000416.html).)

Comment: There are many web pages that have one button highlighted to indicate the default action if the user presses the enter key.  How do I do the same?  How do I tell the browser to draw a given button as the default button?

Comment: @user823527, I still don’t see why you would do that in this case (where a much better approach exists), but if you wish to imitate something you’ve seen, look at its source code—and post a question with a URL if you really cannot figure out how they do that.

Answer (score 0):

By default, buttons are drawn by the operating system, and the browser doesn't control how they look.  If you start changing the CSS properties of a button, the browser takes over and draws the button in its own way.  If you're looking for an easy way to get nice looking buttons with different colours, try bootstrap.  It's a **very** good CSS stylesheet, especially when it comes to construction great looking forms.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/